# Adobe CQ/AEM - trigger afteredit handler

Tags: javascript, aem

When I select "OK" in a component editor dialog, the component redraws itself, assuming I've got the _cq_editConfig.xml set up:

```
    <cq:listeners
    jcr:primaryType="cq:EditListenersConfig"
    afteredit="REFRESH_SELF"/>
```

What I'd like to do is trigger "afteredit" via javascript. I've got a situation where the content has been changed and the author should have an updated view of the rendered component, but I don't know how to do this short of reloading the entire page or opening and closing the edit dialog. Presumably, the function that is represented by the "REFRESH_SELF" constant could be called, but I don't know how to trace the constant back to the function.

Does anyone know how to trigger afteredit from javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the REFRESH_SELF constant is mapped to the method CQ.wcm.EditBase.refreshSelf. You can find its definition by going to /libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/widgets/wcm/EditBase.Listeners.js using crxde. To trigger it by javascript you need first to have the editable object and then call the method. For example:

```
    var ed = CQ.WCM.getEditable('/path/to/the/object/in/page');
    ed.refreshSelf();
```

Comment: Your example worked perfectly for me. Thanks for also letting me know where the code is - very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

@jwepurchase if all you want to do is reload the page after dialog edit or close, you can change the default "REFRESH_SELF" parameter of "afteredit" to "REFRESH_PAGE". It comes OOTB and it's unnecessary to write a script to achieve this functionality.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
cq:actions="[text: Banner Tile,edit,delete,insert]"
cq:dialogMode="floating"
cq:disableTargeting="{Boolean}true"
jcr:primaryType="cq:EditConfig">
<cq:listeners
    jcr:primaryType="cq:EditListenersConfig"
    afterdelete="REFRESH_PAGE"
    afteredit="REFRESH_PAGE"/>
</jcr:root>
```

Reference -> Scroll down to the very end of this page https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/developing/components/edit_config.html

Comment: @jwepurchase wants to refresh component using javascript, not to just refresh page after edit/close

Comment: The link you provided doesn't contain any info relating to this question...maybe adobe changed the page contents...