# how to refresh a page of full data population automatically

Tags: content-management-system, aem

I have a list of data which are been read from an xml file(in dam) in a component and suppose get populated in the entire page. As soon as I read the file in the component, it refreshes the page due to editConfig setting, however, in order see the full data the page(read from xml), I have to do a manual refresh again in the browser.

Is there a way to automate the entire process such that manual refresh can be done away with.

Here is the editConfig setting:

```
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    cq:dialogMode="floating"
    cq:disableTargeting="{Boolean}true"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:EditConfig">
    <cq:listeners
        jcr:primaryType="cq:EditListenersConfig"
        afteredit="REFRESH_PAGE"/>
```

Comment: Are you trying to refresh your component via javascript? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35186800/adobe-cq-aem-trigger-afteredit-handler

Comment: no, I am not, just using the edit config option for refresh

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be an useful solution for your problem. 
https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-tools/features/live-reload.html